# MySQL - What's the correct way of creating multi-column tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to create a `club` table, that will serve as filter when picking players to somebodys own `team`. Such `club` should consist of some important columns such as `id`,`name`,`tag`,`federation`, but it also must contain information of about 50 `player_id`, since it consists of such amount of players.

There's of course the easiest (longest and least reliable also?) way to do that - simply `CREATE` additional 50 columns, name them `player1` ... `player50`, but i'm wondering if there's any better kind of approach to such situations? Maybe storing it as single string (`player1,player2,player3...`) and then split into into array of assosiative `id` in php?

Let me know what are your thoughts on it.

Here's a SQL fiddle in case it appeared to be useful for anybody out there:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b786b4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to normalize the data so it will be easy to work with. You should use two different tables:

```
Club(ID,Name,Tag,Federation)
Club_Players(ID,Player_ID,Club_ID)
```

Under this scheme, the player roster is distributed across *rows*, not columns.  SQL databases are geared up to perform operations over large number of rows, less so columns.  In addition, this approach makes it easy to add a new player; we just need to add a new row.  Under your current approach, we would have to add a new column for each new player beyond 50, which is not a very flexible design.

Comment: I already have a table that contains further player data for each of them (also `club_ID` is there), but filter-wise thought it would be better to have it in clubs also. So you suggest that once i want to display ONLY-THIS-CLUBS players i should verify the id of picked club, then look for this id in another tables (`players`) column `club_ID` right?

Comment: Indeed, a simple join between the tables will let you make all the filters you want, and it will be faster and cleaner in that way then manipulating a comma separated string , or maintaining a 60 columns table(that can possibly grow) .